# How to get a reference to the UITabBar in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller

UIActionSheet has a showFromTabBar: method

```
- (void)showFromTabBar:(UITabBar *)view
```

But how to get a reference to the UITabBar?

I'm currently using

```
UITabBar *tabBar = [self.tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
```

I've also seen someone traversing tabBarController.view.subviews and looking for the UITabBar instance. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 19):

You can use

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using interface-builder you can define something like this as a member in your class interface:

```
IBOutlet UITabBar* tabbar;
```

And connect this outlet to the UITabBar via interface-builder (the UITabBar should be inside the tabBar controller when viewing the xib document window in tree-view mode). Then just use this tabbar member to reference it in your code.